# Search for substring inside string

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex

I have been typing a string inside a textfield, `"KD-G435MUN2D"`.

I already use this code to search for `"UD"` substring from that string:

```
<script>
     var str="KD-R435MUN2D";
     var patt1=/UD/gi;
     document.write(str.match(patt1));
</script>
```

But this code doesn't work. Where is my fault?

---

```
var str = $(this).val; 
var hasUD; 
var hasJD; 
var patt1 = str.match(/u/gi); 
var patt2 = str.match(/J/gi);
var patt3 = str.match(/D/gi); 

if (patt1 && patt3) { 
        hasUD = 'UD'; 
}elseif (patt2 && patt3) { 
        hasJD = 'JD'; }
```

---

I've tried this and it appears to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str="KD-R435MUN2D";
var patt1=/U.*D/g;
document.write(str.match(patt1));

</script>
```

Comment: That's because UD isn't in your string!

Comment: how to modify that script?that i can search "U" and "D" characters and show result like "UD"...

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Maybe you mean:

  `if (str.matches(/U.*D/)) {
    document.write("UD");
  }`

Comment: i already use meredith L. Patterson answer then modify my answer...it make my result show more specific..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will return 'UD' if it has both a U and a D. Otherwise it will be false.

```
var str = "KD-R435MUN2D";
var hasUD;
var patt1 = str.match(/U/gi);
var patt2 = str.match(/D/gi);

if (patt1 && patt2) {
    hasUD = 'UD';
} else {
    hasUD = false;
}

document.write(hasUD);
```

Comment: how to modify that code if  var str="KD-S35JwD"; and i want search JD ?

Comment: change str.match(/U/gi) to str.match(/J/gi)

Answer (score 0):

That will only match U and D together. Try:

```
var str="KD-R435MUN2D";
var patt1=/[U|D]/gi;
alert(str.match(patt1));
```

This will return 'U,D,U'

Comment: how if i want show the result like "UD" after search "U" and "D" characters?

Comment: Do you have to have 'UD'  returned exactly or can you be fine with a Boolean true if it has both a U and a D?

Comment: i think..i'm better use show the result more specific and use /u.*d/g

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the characters UD consecutively in your test string, and your regex specifies only the substring UD. If you're looking for `U[anything]D`, you'll need to use `/U.*D/gi` -- the `.*` means "zero or more repetitions of any valid character" (not counting newline). This will find UD, if it's there, or in your case, UN2D.

Comment: i want search "U" and "D" characters..after that i want to show the result as "UD"..how to make that works?

Comment: Do you care whether they're immediately consecutive or not? Do you care if the D comes before the U? Your question is vague.

Comment: may be better i'm use /u.*d/gi because it more specific